# Xlwings: AddComment generates a Text pywintypes.com_error

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

**Windows 10, Python 3.6, xlwings 0.24.9**

**Example:**

```
xlsx_book = xw.books.active
sht = xlsx_book.sheets['this tab']

sht.range('B5').value = 3
sht.range('B5').api.AddComment('model #3')
```

**Although the comments gets inserted, the code still throws the following:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive -
> xxx.py", line xxx, in 
> sht.range('B5').api.AddComment('model #3')   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py",
> line 70, in **call**
> v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.6\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py",
> line 33496, in AddComment
> ret = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(1389, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((12, 17),),Text
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)

Any lead what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`.api.Comment.Text()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.comment.text):

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book()
ws = wb.sheets[0]
ws.range('A1').api.AddComment()
ws.range('A1').api.Comment.Text('Some Text')
```

Note that it is not possible to use `ws.range('A1').api.AddComment()` if there is already a comment assigned in the cell in question (in this case `A1`). If this is the case you would have to use only `ws.range('A1').api.Comment.Text('Some Text')` or `ws.range('A1').note.text = 'Some Text'`.